# .xls file exceed max number of rows

Tags: python, excel, xlwt

I need to create a file that **has to be in .xls format**, to accomplish that I am using `xlwt` and `xlrd` python modules. As the program generate really large files, the following exception is raised.

```
    raise ValueError("row index was %r, not allowed by .xls format" % rowx)
ValueError: row index was 65536, not allowed by .xls format
```

The solutions that I found say to use `openpyxl` and save as .xlsx because the number of rows can be more than 1 million, but I need the file in `.xls` format, what I can do to accomplish that?

Comment: You can't.  That's just a fact.  You'll have to change the format or choose a different method of storing.  A user can't handle a spreadsheet with a million rows anyway.

Comment: Depending on your code you could try catch, get the row index and build an addition file. I'm sure there is a more elegant solution/ some cases might lock the code.

Comment: @TimRoberts Is not for humans, I need to upload this file on a platform that just accepts this format.

Comment: Actually, you can't, but you can use different sheets, when 65k rows are over.

Comment: Will it accept CSV files?   You can create a CSV file of arbitrary length.

Comment: There are other hard (like diamond) limits in Excel like 32768 characters/cell.

Comment: I did what @Danielme said, it is working.

Comment: I am a little busy right now and do not time to look at the documentation. I would see if there is anything built in for file sizes that are too large. Maybe you can convert to csv so all the data is in one place and convert to .xls when you need it? But glad to hear you have a current fix.

Comment: I will check if it's possible using this method, maybe will perform better, if I make it I will comment here.